# What font does Apple use on iPhone?

Tags: fonts

I like the font, it is very clear to read it even when the text is very small and it looks very neat.

Answer (score 5):

The iPhone 4 uses **Helvetica Neue,** a refined version of Helvetica [[source](http://daringfireball.net/2010/06/4)].

Earlier iPhones use **Helvetica.**

Apple makes use of other typefaces too. **Marker Felt** was adopted for the iOS Notes app, although the latest version now uses a custom Apple typeface called '[**Noteworthy**](http://www.macrumors.com/2011/05/17/apple-trademarks-name-for-a-new-app-called-noteworthy/)'.

Answer (score 2):

> The most recent iPods (and the iPhone)
>   use Helvetica as their UI font.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typography_of_Apple_Inc.

Comment: ...though it's worth nothing that part of the reason the text is so clear, particularly at those small sizes, is that the [pixel density of the phone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density#Apple_Inc.) itself is *much* higher than that of say, your [desktop monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density#Standard-aspect_display).